# Read documents(Python)

Tags: python

I would like Python to read my document, but then it gives an error. Do you know how I can solve this problem?

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/Basis/venv/Python.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(document.read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Please post your code and error here as text, not an image.

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Edit your question with a [mcve] and everything that's required to reproduce

Comment: It seems you are trying to open a Word document. You cannot use Python's built-in `open` to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open a document with the extension `.docx`, which cannot be done with the `open()` function. Instead, you can try using the `docx2txt` library, as follows:

```
import docx2txt
my_text = docx2txt.process("test.docx")
print(my_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

please put full code so else can see what issue you facing

I am sharing the code for how to read or write any file in python

try to run code in python shell.  may be your editor not configure properly

```
>>> f = open('workfile', 'rb+')
>>> f.write(b'0123456789abcdef')
16
>>> f.seek(5)      # Go to the 6th byte in the file
5
>>> f.read(1)
b'5'
>>> f.seek(-3, 2)  # Go to the 3rd byte before the end
13
>>> f.read(1)
b'd'
```

more reference you can refer to this one

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html